# Integration tests test script enqueue/register fails

Tags: oop, testing, unit-tests

This question is related to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722315/integration-testing-of-a-wordpress-plugin-that-needs-composer-and-npm-to-be-exec)

I'm testing a plugin, and in it I have

```
public function enqueue_scripts() {
    $main_style = 'public/scripts/application.js';

    wp_register_script( 'plugin-scripts', plugin_dir_url( __DIR__ ) . $main_script, array() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin-scripts' );
}
```

The plugin is using `composer` and `npm`, so it needs to be built to work.

And it is built (locally where I'm testing it, it works in a local instance I have on VVV). The test I wrote looks like this

```
public function test_enqueued_scripts() {
    $this->admin->enqueue_scripts();
    $this->assertTrue( wp_script_is( 'plugin-scripts' ) );
}
```

`$this->admin` is just an instance of the class where my enqueue method is in the `setUp()` method.

The test fails (`Failed asserting that false is true`), and I wanted to see what's wrong so I added

```
public function enqueue_scripts() {
    $main_style = 'public/scripts/application.js';
    error_log( print_r( plugin_dir_url( __DIR__ ), true ) );
    error_log( print_r( __DIR__, true ) );
    wp_register_script( 'plugin-scripts', plugin_dir_url( __DIR__ ) . $main_script, array() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin-scripts' );
}
```

And ran the unit test, I saw

`http://example.org/wp-content/plugins/Users/dingo_d/vagrant-local/www/projects/project/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/`

For the `plugin_dir_url( __DIR__ )`, and for the `__DIR__` I have

`/vagrant-local/www/projects/project/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/`

The test WordPress instance is located in a temporary folder that looks something like

```
/var/folders/xj/14b3w8w51ll6rw09q72p45cr0000gn/T/wordpress/
```

But my plugins are not installed there. I'm guessing the tests are only using that as a source for the core functionality. Also the `bootstrap.php` file is referencing the `wordpress-develop` that is located in my VVV folder.

What I don't understand is why do I get that `example.org` url? And how can I successfully test the enqueueing/registering of the script?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')` prior to executing your assertions. [This article](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-unit-testing-building-testable-themes--wp-26007) has more details and an example.